# Changing Login Screen on Windows 10 - image doesn't appear to be anywhere

Tags: windows-10, images, login-screen

I work in a school setting and we have a bunch of Windows machines. Some kid took a picture and set it to the background for the Login screen (it's nothing crazy just another kid) andI want to remove the image.

OK, I thought, use the personalization settings as an admin. (One of the kids may have got the admin PW, but it hasn't been changed in a long while, but that's neither here nor there). I go to the "Lock Screen" options and see all the pictures there, but the one I want to get rid of seems to be absent. This picture shows up just after the lock screen, it's the login screen, but there doesn't seem to be a way to change that.

I tried looking for the image on the computer to delete it but even a search with File Explorer yielded no joy; I basically looked up every image file that seemed to fall in the right date range. I didn't see anything that looked right (there's no preview, just a file name)

The other answers I have seen on here all say to go to personalization, but that doesn't seem to be all that helpful so far.

Anyhow any help here would be great. It's not the end of the world but I want to know how someone might accidentally, even, (since the kids don't *really* know what they are doing from a tech perspective a lot of the time) put some image on there that is more problematic, and I want to know how to get rid of it.

Again, to be clear, when I go into personalization and click on the lock screen option the relevant picture isn't visible in the roll of pics the lock screen uses; there does not seem to be a way to get to the login screen image.

Comment: might be a direct registry edit or set via group policy. Varies by Windows version and domain policies I think, but look into that. If I recall correctly, it can be a URL, but unsure if it can be "externally routed" (internet), which if possible might explain your inability to locate the image file. More likely, it is in a hidden appdata folder that folder searches will bypass

Comment: Um, your answer is only partially comprehensible to me. Could you please translate to non techie?

Comment: Try google "windows 10 login image registry group policy"

Comment: that helped a little but but i am begging people to not assume I understand this well, I am not usually a windows guy. The answers I got weren't all that helpful I just need to know what to click on, you know? Pretend I am the dumbest person on Earth.

Comment: If you pretend to be the dumbest person on earth we can't really help you on Super-User which is a forum for PC enthusiasts and power users.  I expect a school with a bunch of Windows machines should have someone supporting same, and you should reach out to them.  We can help you, but you need to meet us halfway, you know.   Have you tried https://www.reddit.com/r/WindowsHelp/  It is more conversational and less structured.